# How to drag an element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm working on a project which needs pictures to be draggable across the page. I found jQuery UI to be a very useful solution which is working as expected but sadly I cannot use it in the project. Instead, I needed to do it using pure javascript only. With some googling, I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Xcb8d/light/

This was perfect, the only problem with it was that it was using IDs which means I can't have multiple draggable items across the page. I modified it to use classes: http://jsfiddle.net/Xcb8d/690/. The problem with the code is that even though both elements were draggable, once you start dragging the second element it's x_elem and y_elem are off. This leads the element to move to a far direction from your mouse. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
var draggables = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable-element');
for(i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
    draggables[i].onmousedown = function () {
        _drag_init(this);
        return false;
    };
}

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

Comment: The first one isn’t perfect as well because it jumps 10px to the bottom and to the right (due to the body’s `padding`). If you change the two lines in `_move_elem` to `selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem - 10) + 'px';` (note the `- 10`) and the same thing for the `y` line, then it becomes flawless. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xcb8d/691/).

Comment: I think, a reliable drag-and-drop only works with absolutely positioned elements…